# using and returning multiple STUArrays

Tags: arrays, haskell, st-monad

I've been working out how to create and use multiple STUArrays in an ST computation. The specific scenarios are:

1. create multiple arrays but return only one of them
2. create multiple arrays but return none of them
3. create multiple arrays and return multiple arrays

I have answers to (1) and (2), but not (3).

First some imports so we know where everything is coming from:

```
import Control.Monad.ST (ST,runST)
import Data.Array.Base (unsafeFreezeSTUArray)
import Data.Array.ST (STUArray)
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray)
import Data.STRef (STRef, newSTRef, readSTRef, writeSTRef)
import Data.Array.MArray (getBounds, newArray, readArray, writeArray, newListArray)
import Data.Array.ST (runSTUArray)
```

For (1), one trick is to define a new data type and constructor function:

```
data ArrayPair s = AP (STUArray s Int Int) (STUArray s Int Bool)

newAP n = do
  a1 <- newArray (1,n) 0
  a2 <- newArray (1,n) False
  return $ AP a1 a2
```

And here's how to return just one of the arrays:

```
foo :: UArray Int Int
foo = runSTUArray $ do
        AP ints bools <- newAP 10
        writeArray ints 1 42
        writeArray bools 1 True
        -- do stuff with ints and bools
        return ints
```

For (2), you can add an `STRef` to the data structure, end the computation with a `readSTRef` and run it with `runST`:

```
data WorkState s = WS (STUArray s Int Int)
                      (STUArray s Int Bool)
                      (STRef s Char)

newWS = do
  ints <- newArray (1,10) 0
  bools <- newArray (1,20) False
  char <- newSTRef 'X'
  return $ WS ints bools char

bar :: Char
bar = runST $ do
  WS ints bools char <- newWS
  writeArray ints 3 36
  writeArray bools 5 True
  writeSTRef char 'Z'
  -- ...
  readSTRef char
```

Comments on this approach for cases (1) and (2)? And what about case (3)?

```
baz :: (UArray Int Int, UArray Int Bool)
baz = runST??? $ do
  AP ints bools <- newAP
  ...
  return (ints,bools)  -- ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use `freeze`. This requires copying arrays, but you don't need to use any unsafe functions:

   ```
   baz :: (UArray Int Int, UArray Int Bool)
   baz = runST $ do
     AP ints bools <- newAP 12
     liftM2 (,) (freeze ints) (freeze bools)
   ```
2. Create your variant of `runSTUArray` for two arrays using `unsafeFreezeSTUArray`, knowing that the implementation is actually safe (because there will be no reference to the original mutable arrays left).

   ```
   runSTUArray2 :: (Ix i1, Ix i2)
              => (forall s . (ST s (STUArray s i1 e1, STUArray s i2 e2)))
              -> (UArray i1 e1, UArray i2 e2)
   runSTUArray2 st = runST $ do
       (a1, a2) <- st
       liftM2 (,) (unsafeFreezeSTUArray a1) (unsafeFreezeSTUArray a2)

   baz' :: (UArray Int Int, UArray Int Bool)
   baz' = runSTUArray2 $ do
     AP ints bools <- newAP 12
     return (ints, bools)
   ```

   (Perhaps this approach could be even somehow generalized using Generics to allow to return any data structure containing `ST` arrays.)

Comment: Thanks! I see where I was getting lost now.